# Cannot turn the front camera on using Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have completed all parts of my app, and now I need to use the front camera to scan instead of the back camera, but having issue of opening it.

Here is the script for the camera.

```
    function scanTrivago()
{
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
            if(!result.cancelled)
            {
                trivagoNumber(result.text);
                path="/confirm-checkin-1/";
        //    alert("Barcode type is: " + result.format);
        //    alert("Decoded text is: " + result.text);
            }
            else
            {
                trivagoNumber(result.text);
              path="/check-in/";
            }
        },

        function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
    );
}
```

I use exactly the function from this site, https://www.sitepoint.com/scanning-qr-code-cordova/ and everything works fine with my simple javascript, but not able to switch the camera to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [plugin docs on github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner#using-the-plugin) have a better example of usage, including a `preferFrontCamera` option:

> A full example could be:

```
   cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      },
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      },
      {
          preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
          showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
          showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
          torchOn: true, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
          saveHistory: true, // Android, save scan history (default false)
          prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
          resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
          formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
          orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
          disableAnimations : true, // iOS
          disableSuccessBeep: false // iOS and Android
      }
   );
```